# Send different emails to 2 different recipients with SendGrid

Tags: php, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using this to send an email to one recipient using SendGrid, but I need to send a different email to a different recipient on the same page. If I duplicate the code block, it emails both recipients the second email when the second code block runs.

```
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgridapikey);
    $emailmaster  = new SendGrid\Email();
    $emailmaster->addTo($to)
    ->setFrom('<email>')
    ->setFromName('<name>')
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setHtml($message);
    $sendgrid->send($emailmaster);
```

Comment: are you emptying $emailMaster after sending the first email

Comment: How would I empty it?

Comment: $emailMaster = null;

Comment: Yes, I tried that it doesn't trigger the second email

Answer (score 0):

Based on [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html) explanation, you can send to multiple reception when you pass `$to` variable as array;

for example;

```
$to[] = "first@email.com";
$to[] = "second@email.com";
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgridapikey);
$emailmaster  = new SendGrid\Email();
$emailmaster->addTo($to)
->setFrom('<email>')
->setFromName('<name>')
->setSubject($subject)
->setHtml($message);
$sendgrid->send($emailmaster);
```

Comment: that didnt work for me. What addTo seems to do is send the email to any recipients who were previously added

Comment: forgot to add emel inside string. after you trying using array, any emel send to sender?